# Algorithm for conditioned migration

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, algebra, bipartite

**Literal description of the problem:**

Given a number of schools, each school holds a number of teachers according to its needs. At the end of the scholar year, some teachers ask for changing their positions (schools where they're currently teaching) according to an ordered list (i.e: change me to school1, if not possible, school2, if not possible school3, etc..) Remembering that each school must have EXACTLY the number of teachers it needs (not more, not less).

Each teacher has an importance number that is unique, so that if two or more teachers ask for the same school at the same time, the one having the higher importance number will get the desired school.

if we are unable to migrate one or more teachers following his list, then we keep him at his initial school answering: "sorry, your demand is affordable for this year"

How can we afford this "migration" ?

(p.s: by "afford" I mean change the position of each teacher to the best (best according to his list) desired school.

---

**I/ Algebraic modeling of the problem**

Given E={e1..en}, n>=0, a set of positive integers (e for entity)

Given L={l1..lm}, m>=0, a set of positive integers (l for location)

Given P:E --> L , a function. (P for position)

Given C:L --> IN*, a function. (C for capacity)

Given U:L --> IN, a function. (U for used) defined by: U(l)=card({e/P(e)=l})

Given A:L --> IN, a function. (A for available) defined by: C(l)=A(l)+U(l) for any l in L.

Let D:E --> L^k, where 0 < k <= m, D(e)=(l1,l2,..li) a function (D for destinations)

(That is, each entity has an ordered non-empty list of locations (destinations) willing to move to).

Let I:E --> IR+, a bijection (I for Importance). (That is, each entity has a unique importance number I(e))

**II/Rules of Migration:**

The asked task, is to find out the new P' function (Positioning) that affords the following:

1- P'(e) belongs to {l1,l2,..,li} where (l1,l2,..,li)=D(e)

2- If we P'(e)=ls and P'(e)=lt are two possible solutions, where D(e) = (l1,...,ls,...,lt,...,li), then we must keep the solution that matches the destinations' order (i.e ls in this case) and exclude the other one)

3-If A(l) = 1 and P'(e1)=l and P'(e2)=l are two possible solutions, where I(e1)>I(e2) then we must keep the solution that matches the importance's order (i.e in this case P'(e1)=l) and exclude the other one.

4- If none of the desired destinations is possible, then P'(e)=P(e)

Comment: This sounds like constraint satisfaction that could be solved using linear programming (simplex). Just search the web. This question is off-topic as it does not concern C. (Once you have the algorithm, start coding and come back f you have problems.)

Comment: Thanks for caring, though, the problem is not a simplex solvable algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

This can be formulated as bipartite matching (or, for efficiency, integer max flow to avoid duplicating the identical positions). Make a graph with a node for each teacher and a node for each position. Put edges between teachers and their current assignments, as well as everything that ranks above their current assignment. Find a maximum matching; if it is not perfect, then the problem is unsolvable without moving a teacher against their preference list.

Otherwise, for each teacher in descending order of importance, determine the best assignment that is feasible and commit to it. There is a linear-time algorithm that, given a bipartite graph with a perfect matching, determines whether there is another matching containing a particular edge (orient the matching edges, the non-matching edge the other way, and look for an augmenting path).

Comment: Thanks David, you put me on the right path:  "bipartite graph" & "maximum matching".

I did a search on the topic and could understand the idea of it.
However, the problem I've presented contains two different views:

The first could be modeled with a  bipartite graph joining teachers with their *CURRENT*  locations (one location for every teacher, not the opposite).

The second is also a  bipartite graph joining teachers with their *DESIRED*  (future) locations.

The important remark here is that when a teacher is assigned a new location, the  bipartite graph will change. 

Any clues?

Comment: @MohamedYOUNES The initial bipartite graph has both kinds of edges. Whenever you settle on an assignment, you delete both endpoints of the corresponding edge (and all of their incident edges).